# Varnish bug in Firebase leads to my website disappearing from the Google Index

Tags: firebase, hosting, varnish, googlebot

There seem to be a nasty bug in Firebase Hosting or Cloud Function that prevents `Googlebot` from crawling pages. As a result, 80% of my website has disappeared on google search.

The error is:

```
Error 503 first byte timeout
Guru Mediation
Details: cache-yvrl...
Varnish cache server
```

I have recorded a short video explaining the issue [here](https://youtu.be/epbfTnAxjYk)

Does this ring a bell??

Comment: Hi @ludovic-fourrage I'm seeing this WITHOUT using GoogleBot as a user-agent.  I think it has to do with firebase hosting and cloud functions but it probably is load or time related.  Did it go away for you?

Answer (score 1):

From a [Varnish-Software blog post](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/understanding-timeouts-varnish-cache)

```
first_byte_timeout (default: 60s) limits how long the processing time of the
backend may be. The first byte of the response must come down the TCP 
connection within this timeout.
```

Check varnishlog and check if Varnish can connect to your backend, sometimes it may be as simple as disabling a firewall